# SAS format char

Tags: sas, char, format

First i have created this table

```
data rmlib.tableXML;

input XMLCol1 $ 1-10 XMLCol2 $ 11-20 XMLCol3 $ 21-30 XMLCol4 $ 31-40 XMLCol5 $ 41-50 XMLCol6 $ 51-60;
datalines;
| AAAAA A||AABAAAAA||  BAAAAA||  AAAAAA||AAAAAAA ||AAAA |
; 
run;
```

I want to clean, concatenate and export. I have written the following code

```
data rmlib.tableXML_LARGO;
file CleanXML lrecl=90000;
set rmlib.tableXML;
array XMLCol{6} ;
array bits{6};
array sqlvars{6};
    do i = 1 to 6;
        *bits{i}=%largo(XMLCol{i})-2;
        %let bits =input(%largo(XMLCol{i})-2,comma16.5);

        sqlvars{i} = substr(XMLCol{i},2,&bits.);


          put sqlvars{i} &char10.. @;
    end;



run;
```

the macro largo count how many characters i have

```
%macro largo(num);
length(put(&num.,32500.))
%mend;
```

What i need is instead of have char10, i would like that this number(10) would be the length, of each string, so to have something like

```
 put sqlvars{i} &char&bits.. @;
```

I don't know if it possible but i can't do it.
I would like to see something like

```
 AAAAA AAABAAAAA  BAAAAA  AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAA
```

It is important to me to keep the spaces(this is only an example of an extract of a xml extract). In addition I will change (for example) "B" for "XPM", so the size will change after cleaning the text, that it what i need to be flexible in the char

Thank you for your time

Julen

Comment: It appears that you are trying to combine data step and macro code in an incorrect manner. Please update your question to include the source code for the `%largo` macro that you are using.

Comment: Also, I suggest you start by writing out what the code would look like if you weren't using any macros, then think how you could use a macro to generate it.

Comment: You showed some input, that is good! Please show and describe the output you want. What does the macro %largo do ?  You are also mixing macro and data step scopes giving the appearance you are hunting for something, anything, that works.

Comment: I included the macro in my first comment. My problem is put together the different strings, being each of them with a different lenght.

Comment: How do you know how long each value should be?  Is it as simple as your initial data step where the length to output is just 2 less than the length with the pipe characters around it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not quite sure what you want to achieve, but if you want to combine the text from multiple varriables into one variable, then you could do something along the lines:

```
proc sql; 
   select name into :names separated by '||' 
   from dictionary.columns 
   where 1=1 
      and upcase(libname)='YOURLIBNAME'
      and upcase(memname)='YOURTABLENAME';
quit;

data work.testing;
   length resultvar $ 32000;
   set YOURLIBNAME.YOURTABLENAME;
   resultvar = &names;
   resultvar2 = compress(resultvar,'|');
run;
```

Wasn't able to test this, but this should work if you replace YOURLIBNAME and YOURTABLENAME with your respective tables. I'm not 100% sure if the compress will preserve the spaces in the text.. But I think it should.

Comment: I was looking for something like $VARYING. Thank all of you for your help. I willl try to use this for the code.

Answer (score 0):

The format `$VARYING. <length-variable>` is a good candidate for solving this output problem.

On the presumption of having a number of variables whose values are vertical-bar bounded and wanting to output to a file the concatenation of the values without the bounding bars.

```
data have;
  file "c:\temp\want.txt" lrecl=9000;

  length xmlcol1-xmlcol6 $100;
  array values xmlcol1-xmlcol6 ;

  xmlcol1 = '|  A |';
  xmlcol2 = '|A BB|';
  xmlcol3 = '|A BB|';
  xmlcol4 = '|A BBXC|';
  xmlcol5 = '|DD   |';
  xmlcol6 = '| ZZZ |';

  do index = 1 to dim(values);
    value = substr(values[index], 2); * ignore presumed opening vertical bar;
    value_length = length(value)-1; * length with still presumed closing vertical bar excluded;
    put value $varying. value_length @; * send to file the value excluding the presumed closing vertical bar;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you it worked with $varying. I need to find how to keep the spaces when i put all the string together but the format worked. Really thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have some coding errors in that is making it difficult to understand what you want to do.

Your `%largo()` macro doesn't make any sense. There is no format `32500.`. The only reason it would run in your code is because you are trying to apply the format to a character variable instead of a number. So SAS will automatically convert to use the `$32500.` instead.

The `%LET` statement that you have hidden in the middle of your data step will execute BEFORE the data step runs.  So it would be less confusing to move it before the data step.

So replacing the call to `%largo()` your macro variable BITS will contain this text.

```
%let bits =input(length(put(XMLCol{i},32500.))-2,comma16.5);
```

Which you then use inside a line of code. So that line will end up being this SAS code.

```
sqlvars{i} = substr(XMLCol{i},2,input(length(put(XMLCol{i},$32500.))-2,comma16.5));
```

Which seems to me to be a really roundabout way to do this:

```
sqlvars{i} = substr(XMLCol{i},2,length(XMLCol{i})-2);
```

Since SAS stores character variables as fixed length, it will pad the value stored. So what you need to do is to remember the length so that you can use it later when you write out the value.  So perhaps you should just create another array of numeric variables where you can store the lengths.

```
sqllen{i} = length(XMLCol{i})-2;
sqlvars{i} = substr(XMLCol{i},2,sqllen{i});
```